# undefined local variable or method `stop' for #<#<Class:0xb085c0a4>:0xb16e8c6c>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this is a very common issue, but I can't resolve this with any of the other topics.
this is the issue:

undefined local variable or method `stop' for #<#:0xb16e8c6c>

**app/views/stops/show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>City name:</strong>
  <%= @stop.city %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Arrival time:</strong>
  <%= @stop.Arrival_time %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Route:</strong>
  <%= @stop.Route_id %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_stop_path(@stop) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', stops_path %>
```

**db/schema.rb**

```
create_table "stops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.time     "Arrival_time"
    t.integer  "Route_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.string   "city"
  end
```

**app/controllers/stops_controller**

```
class StopsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_stop, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /stops
  # GET /stops.json
  def index
    @stops = Stop.all
  end

  # GET /stops/1
  # GET /stops/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /stops/new
  def new
    @stop = Stop.new
  end

  # GET /stops/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /stops
  # POST /stops.json
  def create
    @stop = Stop.new(stop_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stop.save
        format.html { redirect_to @stop, notice: 'Stop was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stop }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /stops/1
  # PATCH/PUT /stops/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @stop.update(stop_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @stop, notice: 'Stop was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @stop }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @stop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /stops/1
  # DELETE /stops/1.json
  def destroy
    @stop.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to stops_url, notice: 'Stop was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_stop
      @stop = Stop.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def stop_params
      params.require(:stop).permit(:city, :Arrival_time, :Route_id)
    end
end
```

I don't see where the problem is.. can you help me? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because @stop isn't defined on the show page. You fix this by defining it in the `show` method in your Stop Controller.

I'm assuming the show page will pass a parameter for the shop id. If so you can define it like this:

```
def show
  @stop = Stop.find(params[:id])
end
```